# DataGridTextColumn inquiry

Tags: silverlight, xaml

How can I add this to my DataGridTextColumn?

MouseLeftButtonDown="Item_MouseLeftButtonDown"

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do within `Item_MouseLeftButtonDown`?

Comment: the user will be redirected to a different page.

Comment: I added this to my code:



<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Item_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>

and got this error:
The tag 'EventSetter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'




Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

*copied from comment*

What about - to add `NavigationUri` to grids cell? But if you still want `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` - then create trigger for this action within which navigate wherever you want.

Comment: I added this to my code:



<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Item_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>

and got this error:
The tag 'EventSetter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'




Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mitc You should use http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity and `Interaction.Triggers`